# Are there any studies on "Left vs Right Side" for a floating social share widget?

Tags: social-sharing-buttons

A client wants one of those floating/sticky vertical social bars on the side of every page of their site. Its from AddThis -- you have probably seen them around the web, stuck to a side of the browser, semi-annoying space hogging widget. The widget hides at mobile widths so its not affected by thumbing. Mostly applies to desktop users.

Are there any studies that deal with which side of the browser has more "success" in regards to these sticky social widgets? Not really looking for opinions...a study with solid A/B results of shares or stat gains would be cool. I didn't see too much in the Google with evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positioning of a sidebar depends on the scale of importance and which country is being targeted. This is because some languages are written from left to right and some are written from right to left. [English is left to right](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/why-is-english-written-and-read-left-to-right), so naturally English people will read the page from the left to right, therefor it would make sense to put the important information on the left and the not so important stuff on the right...

There is [plenty of evidence online supporting](http://www.quicksprout.com/2014/04/16/8-powerful-takeaways-from-eye-tracking-studies/) the fact that generally people look on the left and middle more than they do on the right. Look for eye tracking and website heat maps for even more studies.

Comment: Wow that takeaway article is awesome, thanks. The F pattern and headings spark a thought: in order to preserve important left focal and keep clutter minimal, I will suggest to them to do social floater on the right...leaving the left for unobtrusive eye flow. I believe they desire converts more than shares.

Comment: Sticky floats are dated and annoying, I highly recommend you inform your customer they suck. If people are going to like the page, they will... no need to force feed em.

Comment: Dude i completely agree. Social widgets in general are dated, and dont forget bloaty...the only thing nice about them are the counters that make your page win some kind of pseudo popularity contest. I think thats where they were coming from, share-counter envy or something